# How does 2D Game Physics work?

Tags: game-design, physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I build a 2D physics engine?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4585/how-do-i-build-a-2d-physics-engine)

If we take the game Angry Birds that had big success lately I were thinking how do they implement the physics in a game like that?

Your are shooting of your birds and they hit something that will fall off and in turn creating a chain reaction of things either falling or exploding.. Are all this happening with calculations with rules considering all collisions together with gravity etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erin Catto, the guy who wrote the Box2D physics engine has made a lot of good presentations on how to make 2D physics engines.

The general idea is to move your objects in small time steps, calculate intersections and then resolve them iteratively. Check out the GDC talks at http://code.google.com/p/box2d/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted to know.. Did a few searches for a c# .Net 2d engine but seems to be many "dead" projects out there, anyone you would suggest?

Comment: There seems to be quite some c# ports of box2d linked on the home page. http://www.box2d.org/links.html