# Physic engine for snooker/billard game

Tags: physics-engine, billiards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an algorithm for a pool game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7862/is-there-an-algorithm-for-a-pool-game)

I think most billard/snooker games have a lot of problems with their physic engines. They are far away from realistic and you can't really enjoy the game (especially when snooker is your hobby :) )

So I want to try to make an own physic engine (and own snooker game). I think the physic engine is the most important part of such a game. So my question is:

Do anybody know an open physic enginge I can start with? Is there any literature about such physic problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several open source physics engines out there. [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) is a really popular 2D physics-engine. [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/) is a popular 3D physics-engine.

I think these engines are pretty good. My guess is that the lack of realism is mostly due to a poor setup. If you plug in good values into these engines, you'll get a good simulation. Writing such an engine from scratch is going to be a huge task... but here's a [question just about that](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4585/how-do-i-build-a-2d-physics-engine). Maybe you should also consider extending an existing engine instead of writing a new one? That's the point of open source, isn't it?

Comment: That's correct! I'll try to start with the Bullet engine. I hope that my experience help me to find the right setup :)